# migrating from laravel to symfony

Tags: laravel, symfony

im a huge laravel fan, i have been using it for a while and i have no complains .
the problem is i have this client who wants this app made with symfony2 (very specific ) 
can you guys give me some pointers like the equivalent for each major element of laravel in symfony (mvc structure model where controller where orm doctrine) 
i have read about bundle but i just cant grasp how it works everyone says it's a directory of files........ can you guys tell me what's the equivalent of bundles in laravel like that i think i can understand 
thank you guys

Comment: Trying to understand one framework by comparing it to other frameworks seldom ends well.  Work through the Symfony getting started section and try to think the "Symfony" way.  Don't worry.  They share many of the same components and philosophy.

Comment: i thought that way because many of laravel component are symfony's

Comment: Yes, and that’s a good starting point. But: the Symfony full stack framework is about how these components play together – and this is something which cannot be easily explained by comparing it with Laravel. Moreover: IMHO, you shouldn’t think about bundles too much for your application. I’d suggest reading the “Symfony best practices”, as it explains a motiviation behind bundles (or rather: when to use or not to use) and suggests a simple filesystem/project layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some examples:

1. Bundles is like packages.
2. Symfony doesn't have IoC container, read this to use dependency injection: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html

I think this is the most important for starting if you are using laravel.
If you need more help just write.